# Create a virtual field in a sonata's form

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-3.3

Following this documentation

https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/cookbook/recipe_virtual_field.html

I try to do this

```
<?php 
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{

    $formMapper
        .....
    ->add('tancar', 'checkbox',array(
        'virtual_field' => true
        ))
```

Having this error

> The option "virtual_field" does not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference", "compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "empty_data", "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "extra_fields_message", "horizontal_input_wrapper_class", "horizontal_label_class", "horizontal_label_offset_class", "inherit_data", "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters", "label", "label_attr", "label_format", "label_render", "mapped", "method", "post_max_size_message", "property_path", "required", "sonata_admin", "sonata_field_description", "sonata_help", "translation_domain", "trim", "upload_max_size_message", "validation_groups", "value".

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
->add('_action', null, [
                'virtual_field' => true,
                'actions' => [
                    'edit' => [],
                    'delete' => [],
                ],
            ]);
```

Because `virtual_field` is for `_action` or `batch`. In Documention "Some fields including in the various Mappers don’t rely on any actual field in the Model (e.g., _action or batch)."

Comment: https://github.com/anilkumarp0042/phpproject/blob/4ca80e28ec4ed287486d4210c164f85951959489/src/AppBundle/Admin/ArticleCategoryAdmin.php#L27

Answer (score 0):

As it seems this option is to be used in listMapper, I've solved creating this methods in the entity:

```
<?php
public function getTancar()
{
    return false;
}

public function setTancar($value)
{

}
```

Then, I can get this parameter in the controller or in the Admin class (postUpdate method, for example)